# Widget state considered defunct when popping all routes on stack using Get package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

The error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
> E/flutter ( 5345): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.

My `main.dart` defines a `GetPage` called `/home`, which just returns `Wrapper()`. The `Wrapper()` widget is shown below.

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
      if (value.loggedIn == true) {
        return const Forms();
      } else {
        return const Login();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If the user is not logged in, they are shown the `Login` page, otherwise, they are shown the `Forms` page.

After selecting a form called `Issue Parts`, the user is taken to the new page using `Get.to(() => const IssueParts());`.

I have a timer that constantly checks the authentication state on a remote server. When the user is logged off remotely and the `loggedIn` variable is set to false, the app calls `Get.offAllNamed('/home')`. This correctly takes the user back to the login screen. However, the problem is that Android Studio seems to show a soft error pointing to the first line of my `onServerChanged` function below. This function runs during initialization of the `Login` page. How do I properly resolve this?

I tried to post only the minimum amount of code so that the question doesn't get too messy, but if there is something you would like to know, just ask and I can either tell you or I can add it to the question.

```
void onServerChanged({required String? value}) {
    final globalsOneTimeRead = Provider.of<GlobalsProvider>(context, listen: false);

    selectedServer = value;

    if (value == null) {
      serverIPController.text = '';
      dbController.text = '';
      portController.text = '';
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    for (var element in serverList) {
      if (element['ServerName'] == selectedServer) {
        serverIPController.text = element['ServerIP'];
        dbController.text = element['DBName'];
        portController.text = element['PortNum'].toString();
      }
    }

    globalsOneTimeRead.updateServerName(serverName: selectedServer);

    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I just wanted to use it for its navigation. I'm already using provider for state management (although I still need to move some pages away from Stateful, if possible). The problem is that the navigation I am trying to do does it from a place where there is no `context`, so I couldn't use `Navigator.pop(context)`. Maybe the whole architecture for my app is wrong, but I am using a GlobalsProvider to run a function on a timer and log the user out if the function says to do so.

Comment: There is no context in this separate dart file, and passing context to the timer function (and also every other function in this file) seems really messy. But maybe it's the way Flutter is intended to be used? Not sure, still fairly new

Comment: You need proper separation between view layer and model layer and API layer.  Context should only be in the view layer, not below.  To communicate status from the API layer, you need to use meta data or some sort of state management.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz would it be considered bad practice to pass down context from view layer to API layer? I want to define a custom AlertDialog in my API layer once so that I can reuse it on all my widgets in the view layer

Comment: You should ask this question on the discord.  Links to the discord are found at http://flutter.dev/community (near the bottom).